# Prove that the function $f \colon \Bbb{ Q} →\Bbb{ Q}_{≥0}$ given by$ f(x) = x^2$ is not onto.

Tags: functions

Full text of the question:

> Let $\Bbb{Q}$ denote the set of rational numbers (so that $\Bbb{ Q} = \{\frac{m}{n} \mid m, n \in \Bbb{Z}, n \neq 0\}$. Let $\Bbb{ Q}_{≥0}$ denote
>   the set of nonnegative rational numbers. Prove that the function $f \colon \Bbb{ Q} →\Bbb{ Q}_{≥0}$ given by$ f(x) = x^2$  is not onto.

Note: There is a well known fact about square roots that you are welcome to cite
(without proving it) if it is helpful.

Its been too long since Foundations of Algebra, and I don't know what well known fact he is talking about, there's quite a few. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: Let $3 \in \mathbb{Q_{\geq 0}}$, and consider the equation $x^2 = 3$. It has only irrational solutions,which means $f$ is not onto.

Comment: Right! Thank you so much!

Comment: Hihi. Glad to be that helpful to ya.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Does anything map to $2$?